# php clean up regex

Tags: php, regex

hey can i clean up a preg_match in php from this:

```
preg_match_all("/(".$this->reg['wat'].")?(".$this->reg['wat'].")?(".$this->reg['wat'].")?(".$this->reg['wat'].")?(".$this->reg['wat'].")?(".$this->reg['wat'].")?(".$this->reg['wat'].")?/",$value,$match);
```

to look like this:

```
preg_match_all("/
   (".$this->reg['wat'].")?
   (".$this->reg['wat'].")?
   (".$this->reg['wat'].")?
   (".$this->reg['wat'].")?
   (".$this->reg['wat'].")?
   (".$this->reg['wat'].")?
   (".$this->reg['wat'].")?
/",$value,$match);
```

right now each space, it counts as a ling break so it wont return any finds when searching. but it just looks cleaner and easier to read is why i ask you know. i was looking for one of those letters to add after the closing "/" in the regex. thanks

Answer (score 6):

Yes, take a look at the [PCRE_EXTENDED option](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php):

> x (PCRE_EXTENDED)
>     If this modifier is set, *whitespace data characters in the pattern are totally ignored* except when escaped or inside a character class, and characters between an unescaped # outside a character class and the next newline character, inclusive, are also ignored. This is equivalent to Perl's /x modifier, and makes it possible to include comments inside complicated patterns. Note, however, that this applies only to data characters. Whitespace characters may never appear within special character sequences in a pattern, for example within the sequence (?( which introduces a conditional subpattern.

Comment: well this is inside a class so is that why its not working? i added it in and it doesn't find any results.

Comment: This answer has been added to the [Stack Overflow Regular Expression FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22944075/2736496), under "Modifiers".

Answer (score 3):

```
preg_match_all('/('.$this->reg['wat'].'){0,7}/', $value, $match);
```

That should be fairly clean.

Comment: i just typed this on the fly, not that simple

Comment: Then you need to correctly define how simple it is, as I will not give you an answer that is unnecessarily convoluted.

Answer (score 1):

In case it wasn't obvious: (and as an extension/simplified version of VolkerK's answer) add the x flag to the preg_match call:

```
preg_match_all(".../x",$value,$match);
```

This will allow you to use newlines without regex actually matching them.